# PHP - Find percentage value from string

Tags: php, percentage

I am trying to find the percentage from a string

```
`...Estableciendo conexión...
...Protocolo Sombra v1.95 iniciado...

...Transmitiendo información a ómnicos activos... 61.2855% 

...Terminando conexión...`
```

I am using preg_match to try grab the percentage. But it only grabs the value outside of the decimal, so instead of getting 61.2855 I get 2855.

```
if (preg_match("/[0-9]?[0-9]%/", $crimeexe, $matches)) {
$crimeexe = $matches[0];
}
```

Comment: You are not accounting for the decimal in your regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You arent' looking for the `.` character in your regex. Try this one:

```
if (preg_match("/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+%/", $crimeexe, $matches)) {
  $crimeexe = $matches[0];
}
```